# pandas: add several columns which are various aggregates of an existing column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of trades, `price` and `size`

> ```
>                               price   size
> time      
> 2022-04-18 00:00:00.048541    39649.1 0.007
> 2022-04-18 00:00:00.064796    39649.0 0.005
> 2022-04-18 00:00:00.073577    39649.0 0.023
> 2022-04-18 00:00:00.073579    39649.0 0.011
> 2022-04-18 00:00:00.073617    39648.0 0.006
> ```

I would like to create OHLC minute-bars

The following doesn't work, as `open`, `high`, `low` and `close` columns don't exist:

```
df.resample('1t', closed='left', label='right').agg({
    'open': 'first', 
    'high': 'max', 
    'low': 'min', 
    'close': 'last'
})
```

> ```
> KeyError: "Column(s) ['close', 'high', 'low', 'open'] do not exist"
> ```

Specifying an existing column name, `price` for each of the aggregates also doesn't work, as each subsequent aggregation overwrites the next

```
df.resample('1t', closed='left', label='right').agg({
    'price': 'first', 
    'price': 'max', 
    'price': 'min', 
    'price': 'last'
})
```

> ```
>                       price
> time  
> 2022-04-18 00:01:00   39638.5
> 2022-04-18 00:02:00   39628.8
> 2022-04-18 00:03:00   39552.0
> 2022-04-18 00:04:00   39651.7
> ```

I **could** create 4 new columns as a copy of price, and then apply my first attempt at the aggregation

```
df['open'] = df['high'] = df['low'] = df['close'] = df['price']

df.resample('1t', closed='left', label='right').agg({
    'open': 'first', 
    'high': 'max', 
    'low': 'min', 
    'close': 'last'
})
```

> ```
>                       open    high    low     close
> time              
> 2022-04-18 00:01:00   39649.1 39659.4 39605.9 39638.5
> 2022-04-18 00:02:00   39638.5 39657.5 39622.0 39628.8
> 2022-04-18 00:03:00   39628.8 39643.7 39552.0 39552.0
> 2022-04-18 00:04:00   39552.0 39665.7 39550.0 39651.7
> ```

Whilst this works, it just feels a little clunky...

Is there a way to do my OHLC aggregation, specifying the final column label **and** the source column to take the input value from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas already provides [`resample(...).ohlc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.ohlc.html) method out of the box to calculate open, high, low and close values

```
df.resample('1t', closed='left', label='right')['price'].ohlc()
```

---

```
                        open     high      low    close
time                                                   
2022-04-18 00:01:00  39649.1  39649.1  39648.0  39648.0
```

Comment: oh wow - wasn't aware of that! I also need `volume`, which is the sum of traded volume over the minute , and `vwap` which is the volume-weighted-average-price. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: @SteveLorimer AFAIK pandas doesn't provide any builtin method for that. We have to use custom aggregation...